# Why does Odoo 16 not recognize my model that I created?

Tags: odoo

So i'm using the website feature on odoo 16. I need to create a form that registers products and services in the database.
I've created my custom addons and my custom module.
In the module I created my model named Service.

```
from odoo import fields, models
class Service(models.Model):
    _name = "service.model"
    _description = "Service Model"

    name = fields.Char(string="Service Name", required=True)
    description = fields.Text(string="Description")
    price = fields.Float(string="Price", required=True)
    image = fields.Char(string="Image", attachment=True)
```

In my controller file i added a route and a function that takes the data from a form and sends it to the model so that it can be registered in the database.

```
  @http.route('/create_service', type='http', auth='user', methods=['POST'], website=True, csrf=False)
    def create_service(self, **post):
        # Get the form data
        name = post.get('name')
        description = post.get('description')
        price = post.get('price')
        image = post.get('image')

        # Create the service
        service = request.env['service_model'].create_service(name, description, float(price), image)
return request.redirect('/service_list_template')
```

but when i click the submit button on my formula i then get this error:
[image]

And I don't understand why, I tried solving the issue by adding 'depends': ['base','website'] in the **manifest**.py file but it doesn't work. Can you help me please?

Comment: Can you access the `service.model`  from inside the odoo?

Answer (score 1):

There is an example for `res.partner` in module `website_sale`:

```xml
        <record id="base.model_res_partner" model="ir.model">
            <field name="website_form_key">create_customer</field>
            <field name="website_form_access">True</field>
            <field name="website_form_label">Create a Customer</field>
        </record>
```

So for you it should be like

```xml
        <record id="my_module.model_service_model" model="ir.model">
            <field name="website_form_key">create_service_model</field>
            <field name="website_form_access">True</field>
            <field name="website_form_label">Create a Service Model</field>
        </record>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
service = request.env['service_model'].sudo().create_service(name, description, float(price), image)
```

please update this line in your code. I have added `sudo()`.

also, change the field type of the image:

`image = fields.Char` to `fields.Binary`.

there are some other reasons too for it also checks the ir.model.access.csv file and checks that you have given the necessary permission for your new model.
I hope this will work for you.